# Why cqlsh "CREATE" statement creates a "uuid" field as "timeuuid"?

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

Cassandra 3.11.0 
 running inside Ubuntu 16.04.4, JRE-8 
I am trying to create a table with uuid field as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS policy (
  tenant_id         text,
  policy_id         uuid,
  name              text,
  enabled           boolean,
  creation_time     bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY (tenant_id, name)
);
```

After executing this, schema shows "policy_id" created as "timeuuid" instead of "uuid". 
Saw a  [Similar issue] : [creating uuid type field in Cassandra table using CassandraAdminOperations.createTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153983/creating-uuid-type-field-in-cassandra-table-using-cassandraadminoperations-creat)
But is this applicable to cqlsh ?

Dropped table/keyspace and tried again but no luck. 
This is intermittent issue. 
Getting following exception:

```
Exception while loading CQL script:
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Type error: cannot assign result of function system.uuid (type uuid) to id (type timeuuid)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:50)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:68)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:43)
```

Also seen following in cassandra logs:

```
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Column family ID mismatch (found e686a660-8994-11e9-984c-2767f9f5fd28; expected e5d72c80-8994-11e9-b706-831d59206120)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.validateCompatibility(CFMetaData.java:808) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.apply(CFMetaData.java:770) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.Schema.updateTable(Schema.java:621) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.updateKeyspace(SchemaKeyspace.java:1430) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.mergeSchema(SchemaKeyspace.java:1386) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.mergeSchemaAndAnnounceVersion(SchemaKeyspace.java:1336) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.MigrationTask$1.response(MigrationTask.java:91) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.ResponseVerbHandler.doVerb(ResponseVerbHandler.java:53) [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessageDeliveryTask.run(MessageDeliveryTask.java:66) [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:81) [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
```

policy_id should have datatype "uuid" but it has datatype "timeuuid". 
Any additional keyword required in cql statement to create table?

Comment: How do you check that policy_id is timeuuid? I tried to replicate your issue and did a DESC on the table but policy_id is uuid.

Comment: Thanks Simon,I connected from Devcenter and checked schema, it showed timeuuid.